# How to send unicode characters in an HttpPost on Android

Tags: android, http, unicode, post, encoding

I'm trying to allow multilingual support in my app which makes an HTTP post to upload new messages.  What do I need to do in order to support japanese & other non latin based languages?  my code currently looks something like this:

```
    //note the msg string is a JSON message by the time it gets here...
private String doHttpPost(String url, String msg)
        throws Exception {

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(msg);
    post.setEntity(stringEntity);


    return execute(post);
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try setting encoding on StringEntity:

```
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(msg, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I have same problem would you help me on this?