# how to send unicode charcters in http post request from asyncTask

Tags: android, unicode, android-asynctask

I saw this post [How to send unicode characters in an HttpPost on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084462/how-to-send-unicode-characters-in-an-httppost-on-android) but I usaully do request in this way in AsyncTask class.My log is also printing local language in urlParameters but server is returning no result while it is perfect for english Strings:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... URLs) {

    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        URL obj = new URL(URLs[0]);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        // add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        if (URLs[0].equals(URLHelper.get_preleases)) {
            urlCall = 1;
        } else
            urlCall = 2;

        // String urlParameters = "longitude=" + longitude + "&latitude="+latitude;

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response.toString();
}
```

Is there a way to set character set UTF-8 to request parameters coding this way?

Comment: [how-to-send-unicode-characters-in-an-httppost-on-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084462/how-to-send-unicode-characters-in-an-httppost-on-android)

Comment: @SilentKiller thats what he posted in question :)

Comment: @DIVA please check whether this line is available in the above code `StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(msg, "UTF-8");` He is not providing charSet anywhere.

Comment: @SilentKiller u r right , the link you provided is same as he provided ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> String urlParameters = "longitude=" + longitude + "&latitude="+latitude;

You need to URL-encode components you are injecting into an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` context. (Even aside from non-ASCII characters, characters like the ampersand will break otherwise.)

Specify the string-to-bytes encoding that you are using for your request in that call, for example:

```
String urlParameters = "longitude=" + URLEncoder.encode(longitude, "UTF-8")...
```

...

> DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

A `DataOutputStream` is for sending struct-like Java-typed binary data down a stream. It doesn't give you anything you need for writing HTTP request bodies. Maybe you meant `OutputStreamWriter`?

But since you already have the string all in memory you could simply do:

```
con.getOutputStream().write(urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

(Note the `UTF-8` here is somewhat superfluous. Because you will already have URL-encoded all the non-ASCII characters into `%xx` escapes, there will be nothing to UTF-8-encoded. However in general it is almost always better to specify a particular encoding than omit it and revert to the unreliable system default encoding.)

> new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())

is also omitting the encoding and reverting to the default encoding which is probably not the encoding of the response. So you will probably find non-ASCII characters get read incorrectly in the response too.